# When Using NVD3 Line Chart Draws Erratically

Tags: javascript, charts, nvd3.js

I'm wondering if anyone might be able to help with an issue I'm having with NVD3 where the chart occasionally gets drawn erratically.  This typically occurs when I leverage the toggle for labels (i.e. where you can show or hide different lines).  The result is something that looks like the following image:

[image]

Initially the chart looks normal (i.e. a single line).  However, after enabling and disable other lines on the chart, the image ends up being drawn in the erratic fashion shown above.

Any help on how to address this would be greatly appreciated.  I was not sure what to search for to describe the issue so apologies if the answer was readily available.

Comment: Can you post the code for the chart? Preferably in a jsfiddle or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs across this (which is actually unlikely) I tracked down the issue to the following added lines of code to the "mouseover_line" event (commented out below):

```
            function mouseover_line(evt) {
            var yaxis = data[evt.seriesIndex].yAxis === 2 ? yAxis2 : yAxis1;

            // evt.series.values[evt.pointIndex].x = d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(evt.point.x));
            // evt.series.values[evt.pointIndex].y = d3.format(',')(evt.point.y);

            evt.value = evt.point.x;
            evt.series = {
                value: evt.point.y,
                color: evt.point.color,
                key: evt.series.key
            };
            tooltip
                .duration(0)
                .valueFormatter(function(d, i) {
                    return yaxis.tickFormat()(d, i);
                })
                .data(evt)
                .hidden(false);
        }
```

I had added those lines in to fix the hover over labels for the line graph (my line graphs had a datetime x-axis and comma separated integer y-axis).  Upon adding those lines it seems the extra processing time required resulted in the lines drawing eratically whenever you toggle a series on/off.

Not too sure what the mechanism is that causes the issue but those lines were the root cause.